# kivy 1.10.1 and 1.11.0 not working on raspberry pi4 Buster

Tags: raspberry-pi, kivy

I just received my new raspberry pi4 and did a fresh install with the latest Raspian buster. I installed the latest kivy 1.11 and I cannot have it running. Kivy just get frozen at the start what application you are trying to open.

I also tried to do a fresh install of kivy 1.10.0 on my raspberry PI4 and the problem is the same.

Is there known issues or tricks to have kivy running on PI4 ?

I tried to start an apps I wrote which work working fine on Raspberry PI3 and Raspian.

I added log level = debug but don't see much in the logs.

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/asysclay/.kivy/logs/kivy_19-07-09_3.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/home/asysclay/Container/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/__init__.pyc"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.16 (default, Apr  6 2019, 01:42:57) 
[GCC 8.2.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/home/asysclay/Container/bin/python"
[WARNING] [Deprecated  ] Python 2 Kivy support has been deprecated. The Kivy release after 1.11.0 will not support Python 2 anymore
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.lang> with limit=None, timeout=None
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.image> with limit=None, timeout=60
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.atlas> with limit=None, timeout=None
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.texture> with limit=1000, timeout=60
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.shader> with limit=1000, timeout=3600
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: egl_rpi
[DEBUG  ] [Window      ] Actual display size: 1920x1080
```

I got stuck here and even a Control-C cannot stop the apps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  It appears to be caused by the fact that the text and window providers are different (sdl2 vs. egl_rpi).

Try this test:

export KIVY_WINDOW=sdl2

then run your Kivy program.

If it works, then you need to make the environment change permanent, or put the following at the head of each Kivy python file you write:

import os
os.environ["KIVY_WINDOW"] = "sdl2"
os.environ["KIVY_TEXT"] = "sdl2"

But to be honest, there are probably better solutions.  This should work to get you over the hump.

Comment: using export KIVY_WINDOW=sdl2 helped me in this case

Answer (score 0):

The reply from Prince Hal was very helpful to me to get Kivy 1.11.1 working with Raspbian Buster on a Rpi 3B+.  I run this without loading the desktop/window manager.  The Kivy application is launched from the console at boot.  The last thing that frustrated me is that there was no mouse cursor visible but its functions were there in the background.  Setting this environment variable fixed that problem : )